# Reference request: Best book to cite on a property of the family of Cauchy distributions

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

Kai Lai Chung once began a section of a textbook on probability by writing

> "Everybody knows" that $$ e^x = \sum_{n\,=\,0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

(with those quotation marks). Other mathematicians sometimes write "It is well known that [etc. etc.]". I found myself tempted to do that in the following situation:

The standard Cauchy distribution is the probability distribution
$$
\frac{dx/\pi}{x^2 + 1}
$$
on the real line. This has median $0$ and interquartile range $2.$ If $X$ has this distribution, then $\mu + \sigma X$ is also said to have a Cauchy distribution. This has median $\mu$ and interquartile range $2\sigma,$ and can written in the form
$$
\frac{\sigma\,dx/\pi}{(x-\mu)^2 + \sigma^2}.
$$

So I found myself about to write that it is well known that this family of probability distributions is **invariant** under **linear fractional transformations** of random variables, i.e. if $X$ has a Cauchy distribution with parameters $\mu, \sigma$, then for real numbers $a,b,c,d,$ with $ad-bc\ne0,$ $(aX+b)/(cX+d)$ also has a Cauchy distribution.

Then I thought I ought to cite some source. Among books that can be found in most reasonable libraries (for reasonable values of "most reasonable"), and that give a clear and simple statement and proof of this proposition, which one is best to cite?

Comment: This is a very simple exercise for an undergraduate mathematical statistics course. So, I think you do not need to cite anything. In any publication that uses this property, you would probably find "(very) easy to see" instead of "well known".

Comment: I suppose saying "It is a straightforward exercise to show that [etc.]" doesn't carry the same duty to cite something as saying "It is well know that [etc.]"

Comment: I have this qualm about writing about this family of distributions: $$ \frac{\sigma\,dx/\pi}{(x-\mu)^2 + \sigma^2} $$ seems simpler and nicer than $$ \frac1\pi\cdot\frac{dx/\sigma}{ \left( \frac{x-\mu}\sigma \right)^2 + 1}, $$ but the latter has the advantage of showing that every $\sigma$ that appears goes with an $x.$ For the same reason I prefer to write the normal distribution as $$ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac12 \left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right)\, \frac{dx} \sigma $$ rather than omitting the $dx$ and putting the $\sigma$ in that fraction at the beginning. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is certainly well known, and citing a text book seems overkill, it is good scholarly practice to cite original sources.
You could cite Frank Knight: [A Characterization of the Cauchy Type](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041858):

[image]

Note that this is an equivalence statement (the proof that the invariance implies a Cauchy distribution is considerably more involved than the proof of the converse). The multi-dimensional generalization is known as the Knight-Meyer theorem, see [Une caractérisation de la loi de Cauchy](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00535680).

Comment: Does the "if" part turn out to be a lot less routine than the "only if" part?

Comment: certainly, Knight needs only a few lines for the "only if" part

Comment: That he doesn't also need only a few lines for the "if" part is not clear without knowing how long this is, but it's certainly not as clear how to do it. Tentatively I would give this hint to those doing this exercise, if they want a hint: First reduce the problem to the case in which $a=0.$ Then the whole thing is just a few lines. $\qquad$